# Input submit not included in the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I would like to ask if why the `<input type="submit" value=""` is not included in the form when I tried to debug the form using F12.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>    
        @if (ViewBag.wthOutSupp == false)
        {
            using (@Html.BeginForm("Item_SendForApprovalMail", "BuyersTask", FormMethod.Post))
            {                           
                <td style="border-color:#1e7c97; background-color:#1e7c97" colspan="5">
                    @Html.Hidden("id",(int)@ViewBag.prfNo)
                    <center> <input type ="submit" id="subbttn1" value="Submit the Item/s to Reveiwer" /><center>
                </td>
            }           
        }
        else if  (ViewBag.wthOutSupp == true) {
            using (@Html.BeginForm("OnHoldItems", "SearchItems", FormMethod.Post))
            {                           
                <td style="border-color:#1e7c97; background-color:#1e7c97" colspan="5">
                    @Html.Hidden("id",(int)@ViewBag.prfNo)
                    <center> <input type ="submit" id="subbttn" value="Hold Some Items that Have no Supplier Yet" /><center>
                </td>
            }             
        }
    </tr> 
</table>
```

In the F12 results:

[image]

Could someone help me with this one?

Comment: I see the submit button there! What do you mean submit value is not there?

Comment: Its the 8th line down in your image. What do you means its not there?

Comment: I mean, the submit button was not included inside the form.
`<form action="/BuyersTask/Item_SendForApprovalMail method="post"></form>"`

Comment: Because your creating invalid html. A form cannot be a child element of a `<tr>`

Comment: NOTHING is inside your form, you're immediately closing it with `</form>`.

Comment: @Paul, the Form code is being generated, HE, isn't closing it immediately, as others have mentioned the html is invalid, that's the real issue.

Answer (score 2):

You code is generating invalid html. A `<form>` element cannot be a child of a `<tr>` element.

Change your code to

```
<table>
  <tr>   
    <td style="border-color:#1e7c97; background-color:#1e7c97" colspan="5">
      @if (ViewBag.wthOutSupp == false)
      {
        using (@Html.BeginForm("Item_SendForApprovalMail", "BuyersTask", FormMethod.Post))
        {                           
          @Html.Hidden("id",(int)@ViewBag.prfNo)
          <center> <input type ="submit" id="subbttn1" value="Submit the Item/s to Reveiwer" /><center>
        }           
      }
      else
      {
        ....
      }
    </td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenMuecke! I haven't noticed that.